# PHP MySQL website not working with uppercase

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a website with PHP and MySQL. If the folder name is 'blog' in public directory with 'index.php' in it, then the link 'website.com/blog/' is working perfectly. Now the problem is if I remove the last slash (/), or write any letter in uppercase (like Blog, bloG, BLog, etc.) then it is taking viewer to somewhere else. Any solution? It looks easy, but not able to do it. May be something to do with PHP string functions.

Comment: On Linux servers all file and folder names are case sensitive, you can have a folder named Blog and an other named blog, that's why it doesn't work if you capitalize one of the letters. You can find workarounds with .htaccess, search for "htaccess case insensitive redirect".

Answer (score 0):

In linux Letter [ A ] and [ a ] both different so when you point to /blog this mean folder you created but when you point /Blog this folder is not exist.

You can do these things with apache or nginx but with child URL's not parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple 3-step solution if you're using Apache:

1. Use only lower case in your folder and filenames
2. Add a lowercase transformation (RewriteMap) to your server config
3. Use `.htaccess` to rewrite all URLs from the browser to lower case

The first step is simple enough; just rename `Blog` to `blog` etc...

The 2nd step is done in your site's `Virtualhost` section within the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file where Apache allows you to define websites.  In that section, you add the lowercase map:

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourwebsite.com    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap  lowercase int:tolower
```

Now that we've defined a map named `lowercase` that uses Apache's internal `tolower` map, we can use it in `.htaccess` file to rewrite any URL that contains an uppercase letter to lowercase.  Create a file by that name and put it in the top level public directory of your site -- usually `public_html` or `www`.  Inside this file, add the following rules:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
# Rule below must be above all other rewrite rules
# It says: if path has uppercase, rewrite to lowercase
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Now, all your paths are lowercased (step 1), and if a user tries to go to `/BLOG`, instead taking her somewhere else, the server will redirect to `/blog`

Answer (score -2):

linux server is case sensitive so please rename your folder as it is your path then solve your problem